# ElasticSearch returns Zero Hits with MongoDB-River plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying make "elasticsearch-river-mongodb" plug-in with my local MongoDB instance.

With help from http://satishgandham.com/2012/09/a-complete-guide-to-integrating-mongodb-with-elastic-search/#comment-2871

I am able to get rid of 404 exception. However, all my queries to ElasticSearch index return NO hits.

Following are the steps I have followed in sequence.

1. Installed MongoDB 2.4.3
2. Enabled ReplicaSet = rs0
3. Enabled oplogSize = 100
4. Restarted MongoDB Server
5. Configured the rsConf variable on MongoShell
6. Initiated the ReplicaSet

---

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-05-21T17:42:41Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 865,
            "optime" : {
                "t" : 1369157994,
                "i" : 1
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-05-21T17:39:54Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

7. Installed ES
8. Installed attachment plugin `(ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/1.4.0)`
9. Installed River plugin `(ES_HOME/bin/plugin -install richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/1.4.0)`
10. Restarted ES
11. Curl ES to index documents from MongoDB with following command successfully.

---

```
purl -XPUT 'http://`127.0.0.1`:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
    "type": "mongodb", 
    "mongodb": { 
        "db": "players", 
        "collection": "scores"
    }, 
    "index": {
        "name": "scoresindex", 
        "type": "score" 
    }
}'
```

---

12. Added  new documents to MongoDB
13. On MongDB `db.oplog.rs.find()` collection returns new updates

---

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find()
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1369152540, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong(0), "v" : 2, "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : { "msg" : "initiating set" } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1369152706, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("7734203254950592529"), "v" : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "players.scores", "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("519b9cc2871b3116f0b8006e"), "name" : "rohit", "score" : 20 } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1369157720, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("2546253279621321716"), "v" : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.scores", "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("519bb058b6fd31855ec8b0af"), "name" : "karthik", "score" : 20 } }
{ "ts" : { "t" : 1369157994, "i" : 1 }, "h" : NumberLong("-3356531630527802451"), "v" : 2, "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.scores", "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId("519bb16ab6fd31855ec8b0b0"), "name" : "dinesh", "score" : 20 } }
```

---

The problem i am facing is : Searching  on ElasticSearch using following command

---

```
curl -XGET 'http://`127.0.0.1`:9200/scoresindex/_search?q=name:dinesh'
```

---

for newly added document to scores collection on MongoDB does not return any results.

I have tried posting document directly to ES and it DOES return the results but not from the documents in MongoDB.

Is there something i am missing? Appreciate your help in advance.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [project](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) [1](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb) MongoDB 2.4.3 is only supported in version 1.6.6 and above of the river.
Which version of Elasticsearch are you running?

Please take a look a the [wiki page "install guide" section](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki#install-guide).

Thanks,
   Richard.